# How to set a image and font size in a dynamic button using javascript in gmail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, gmail

i have done to set a button in gmail page using the below code.

```
var btn1=document.createElement('input');
btn1.type='button';
btn1.value='mybutton';
btn1.id='btn10';
```

i want to set a image in this button.i tried to set a image using

```
btn1.backgroundImage = 'url(images/aaa.png)';
btn1.background = 'url(images/aaa.png)';
```

but the image not set in that button and i try to change the font size for  `btn1.value='mybutton';` it also not working.

```
btn1.style.fontFamily = "arial";
                btn1.style.background = "#3C80EE";
                btn1.style.color = "white";
                btn1.style.Text ="small";
```

In the above code background and color only set in that button.fontFamily could not changed.
the Text Style totally reduce the button size not only font size.

So how to change the font size and how to set the background image in that gmail page using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
btn1.style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/aaa.png)';
or
btn1.style.background = 'url(images/aaa.png)';
```

Perhaps your lowercase "arial" might be causing the font family issue. Try making "Arial"

Use Object.style.fontSize to control the buttons font size

Comment: @ Grimmus : all your suggesstions are already tried,but it not works.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle ?